# How to pass data from root file(main.dart) to different pages like android broadcast receiver in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass the data periodically from the `main.dart` file to the currently visible screen. Which flutter component I want to use in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Stream.periodic](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Stream/Stream.periodic.html) functionality and [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. Below a simple example:

Create a `business logic component`

```
class Bloc {
  /// Stream controller
  final _streamController = StreamController<Object>.broadcast();

  /// Object sink (send objects here)
  void sink(Object value) => _streamController.add(value);

  /// Object stream (listenable for objects)
  Stream<Object> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

This is a `main page` wrapper (i.e. app):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bloc = Bloc()

  MyApp() {
    // Send object to stream each minute
    Stream.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (count) {
      bloc.sink(count);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Some App',
      theme: hemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // Provide `Bloc` object for `MainScreen` widget and its children
      home: Provider<Bloc>(
        create: (_) => bloc, // already created bloc
        dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),  // bloc will be disposed automatically
        child: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a `MainScreen`:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Bloc to use in this screen
  Bloc bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Take `bloc` from widget tree (it is provided via `Provider` above
    bloc = Provider.of<Bloc>(context);
    // Subscribe for listening of objects
    bloc.stream.listen((object) {
      // Do some action when object received
      print('$object');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```